# How do I customize the namespace in code generated by protobuf-net

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I have a proto file as follows

```
import "protobuf_net.proto";
option (protobuf_net.namespace) = "My.Test";

enum TestEnum {
    FIRST = 0;
    SECOND = 1;
    THIRD = 2;
}
```

I'm expecting the resulting `TestEnum` to be in the `My.Test` namespace, but the namespace is just the name of the file (or a package if I define one). Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: wow, I have absolutely no recollection of `protobuf_net.namespace` - I'd better check that is handled!

Comment: As an aside, unless you are planning to use interop to other platforms, you don't actually **need** a .proto *at all* - you can just have a C# enum and C# classes, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, the protos are already used by a Java system, which is also why I'd like to find a solution similar to java_package for the namespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From memory, this uses the existing proto syntax

```
package My.Test {
     enum TestEnum {
        FIRST = 0;
        SECOND = 1;
        THIRD = 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm just looking through your code. So the namespace is chosen in this order: 1. From the package 2. Otherwise from the default namespace (ns) 3. From the file name. So I guess the custom option wasn't added. I'm gonna have a go at adding it, I'll send you a patch if I get anywhere...